# TypError: Object function model has no method "checkDisponibility"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Im trying to create some functionality methods for my model, but when i send a request it returns me this traceback:

```
/home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:413
        throw err;
              ^
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model))
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'checkDisponible'
    at /home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/app/routes/facturas.js:33:18
    at Function.forEach (/home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:3297:15)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/app/routes/facturas.js:32:9)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Promise.emit (/home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    at handleSave (/home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:133:13)
    at /home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:408:16
    at /home/nano/Dev/JS/OMI/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js:125:9
```

The problem is, well, i declared the function method in the Schema, before the model compilation, as stated in the documentation:

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  descripcion: String,
  costo: Number,
  precioMin: Number,
  precioMax: Number,
  existencia: Number,
  disponible: Number,
});

itemSchema.methods.checkDisponible = function(itemId, cant) {
  this.findById(itemId, function(err, item) {
    if (err)
      return false;
    if (item.existencia >= item.disponible && item.disponible >= cant)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  });
};

var Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
```

This is the route code:

```
crear: function(req, res) {
    var nuevaFactura = {
      _id: req.body._id,
      cantidadItem: req.body.cantidadItem,
      condPago: req.body.condPago,
      decripcion: req.body.descripcion,
      monto: req.body.monto,
      items: [],
      cliente: req.body.cliente
    }, 
    factura;

    _.forEach(req.body.items, function(item) {
      nuevaFactura.items.push(item);
    });

    factura = new Factura(nuevaFactura);

    factura.save(function(err, factura) {
      if (err)
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: "error interno en la base de datos creando factura", error: err });

      _.forEach(factura.items, function(item) {
        if (Item.checkDisponible(item, factura.cantidadItem)) {
          Item.findById(item, function(err, token) {
            if (err)
              return res.status(500).json({ msg: "error interno en la base de datos actualizand item", error: err });
            token.existencia = token.existencia - factura.cantidadItem;
            token.disponible = token.disponible - factura.cantidadItem;

            token.save(function(err) {
              if (err)
                return res.status(500).json({ msg: "error interno en la base de datos guardando cambios en item", error: err });
            });
          }); // fin Item.findById
        } else {
          return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No hay existencia o disponibilidad del producto', item: item }); 
        }
      }); // fin _.foreach

      Cliente.update({ _id: factura.cliente }, { $push: { facturas: factura._id } }, function(err) {
        if (err) 
          return res.status(500).json({ msg: "error interno en la base de datos actualizando cliente", error: err });
      }); // fin Cliente.update

      res.status(200).json({ msg: 'Factura creada', factura: factura });
    }); // fin factura.save
  }, // fin crear
```

i know, is a dirty code but it's just a draft.

Thanks for all!

Comment: Hi Nano, would you mind including all the code for the files in question? I'm trying to follow the line numbers in the stack trace. Also, I see that you are calling a function named `Item.checkDispAndExit`, but I don't see where that function is declared.

Comment: Hi @lukewestby i changed the `checkDispAndExist` for the correct method name `checkDisponible` but the error is still there.

[Here](https://github.com/nanotime/OMI/blob/master/app/models/models.js) and [here](https://github.com/nanotime/OMI/blob/master/app/routes/facturas.js) is the complete code of models and the specific route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see is that you are registering `checkDisponible()` as a `method`, but what you really want is to register it as a `static`. Functions on the schema's `methods` object will be callable from model instances, but functions on the `statics` object will be callable from the model constructor, the way that you are calling it.

```
itemSchema.statics.checkDisponible = function(itemId, cant) {
  //...
};
```

Once that is sorted out, you are going to run into a new issue. Inside of `checkDisponible()` you  are calling `findById()` which is an async function. You can't simply return the result, you'll have to modify `checkDisponible()` to either accept a callback or return a promise. I'll provide the callback version here just so it's clear what I'm getting at.

```
itemSchema.methods.checkDisponible = function(itemId, cant, cb) {
  this.findById(itemId, function(err, item) {
    if (err)
      cb(false);
    if (item.existencia >= item.disponible && item.disponible >= cant)
      cb(true);
    else
      cb(false);
  });
};
```

---

```
_.forEach(factura.items, function(item) {
  Item.checkDisponible(item, factura.cantidadItem, function(result) {
    if(result) {
      //...
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Really, thanks, i have just one question, how i can know if a function in mongoose is async? All of them are?

Comment: All of the query and update methods are. Any time you are passing a callback you can expect the function to be called at a later time. This is where much of the power of Node and MongoDB comes from - asynchronous I/O